# Secondary Axis in axlsx charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, axlsx

I am working on the xlsx report generation, and for that I am using `axlsx` gem. I looking for the option to show secondary **Y-axis** (for 2nd series in charts) in line and bar charts. Is there any way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked out the [axlsx documentation](https://github.com/randym/axlsx#documentation)?

Comment: Yes, and I am still searching for it.

Comment: Am I wrong or this example in read me is exactly what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not well versed in axlsx much less charting in general, but from what I've read on the documentation there are thee possible 'axes' to choose from. valAxis, catAxis and serAxis. If I'm to assume you want depth to your chart, use serAxis.

http://rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx/SerAxis