# Specify Intervals in x-axis labels using axlsx gem

Tags: ruby, axlsx

I am working on the `xlsx` report generation, and for that I am using `axlsx` gem. I am facing 2 issues, one of them is as follow and other is asked in separate question [Secondary Axis in axlsx charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558754/secondary-axis-in-axlsx-charts).

The issue I am facing to specify intervals between x-axis labels, which is date axis.

tried following code.

```
chart.catAxis.scaling.logBase = 10
```

Which is mentioned in https://github.com/randym/axlsx/issues/60, But its still showing all labels.
Please help.
Note: I am using libre Office.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't even understand what your question is because you're stating categorically different attempts. Do you want to set an interval or do you want to hide labels?